# Android XML layouts and widgets

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout

Im starting to learn android programming and i was wondering where i could find all of the layouts and widgets basic xml code so i can write it down in a notebook and study it Thank you !

Comment: if your are basic learner go thru the API demos first.

Comment: refer this tutorials : [part1](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts) [part2](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views) [part3](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a nice introduction to the Android XML layouts at the [Android reference pages](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)